# Cannot connect to h2 database in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, h2

I´m trying to follow this tutorial [tutorial](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2018/08/restful-api-spring-rest-data-jpa-h2.html) in Intellij IDEA but when i try to connect to h2 database the console trowns me an error:

```
 Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost:9092" 
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect.
```

What i need to do to make the connection?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: As noted: your url uses tcp for the connection to database. This means the H2 database should be up and running on localhost on 9092 port. Or use `file` connection protocol type as described the the tutorial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the url, it needs to path to your app:
jdbc:h2:file:C:\Users\romul\IdeaProjects\raspberryAwards;MV_STORE=false;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE

Answer (score 7):

Change connection type from "Remote" to "In-memory"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).